# Karunya Pitru Tharpana

Tags: rituals, pitru

Amavasya and monthly tharpanas we perform only for pithrus. But 
during Chaturmasya period, tharpana is being done on Madhya Ashtami or Maha Barani to the pithrus [forefathers] along with Karunya pithru. We keep additional bhugna for karunya pithrus.

Is there any scriptural reference on what basis we perform tharpana for karunya pithru?

Note on Karunya pithru ---  Any elders in the family left home and  died in mysterious circumstances, death caused to them by wild animals etc.

Comment: Very closely related or a duplicate. Very sad that didn't find out your question before that is answered. [What scriptures say about sraddha (श्राद्ध) during pitru paksha for untimely deaths?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/29217/5212)